# Multiple object type container or dynamic casting for a game project?

Tags: c++, casting, containers, allegro5

I have a very specific... well, lets not call it a problem, lets rather call it a deadlock. I'm writing a simple 2d game using allegro5 along with c++, and have a specific problem I'd like to overcome.

Main problem:

Currently, for game loop i'm using a list container, which holds all of my objects (of type GameObject) inside, and then im iterating on it to do things like updating the objects positions, rendering and animatating sprites.

From the class GameObject (which hold generic information used for updating, rendering and memory handling methods) inherits a Creature class, which should handle things like attacking methods.

The problem that comes up is that when iterating my main list of GameObjects (which would include Creatures as well) i cannot directly use the methods of my Creatures class. Of course I understand why I cannot do that (Encapsulation).

So far I've come to few possible solutions (which, in my humble opinion are not perfect), but I would like to ask for help in helping to find easy to implement and efficient solution:
 - Using a container that could hold multiple object types.
 - Using dynamic_cast at some point, to cast a creature GameObjects to Creature class to temporary use Creature methods and variables (is that even possibile?)
 - Setting up a second container for handling the Creature methods and variables (I would like avoid that, as then I would need a single object to be in two containers at once - when adding new types of classes 'buildings', 'obstacles' or 'arrows' thier number will grow!)

I'm a very beginner programmer, and as I understand creating a game could be kind of overkill for my level of skill, im determined to push this game forward with any means nessesary. (Especially since I've learned a lot so far)

I hope I've explained a problem in detail - i'm not posing any code here, as its more of a theoretical problem then practical one, im just iterating a GameObject list after all.

With regards,

Comment: Perhaps the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) would be applicable in this case?

Comment: Instead of using an inheritance based architecture, the [Component-Entity-Systems (read here for example)](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/understanding-component-entity-systems-r3013) are widely used in game development. I don't know if it too late for you to change such design decisions, but its yet worth reading i believe.

Comment: Use composition instead of inheritance. Define one and only one `Entity` class that may contain everything else like `Creature`, or `Position` or other stuff like `CollisionBody`. An entity component system is usually the way it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've found out, containers can only hold one type of object at a time.

If that object type is a base class pointer, it can point to any object derived from the base class. However, you need to first cast the pointer to the appropriate type before you can use it's specific abilities.

You answered your own question when you brought up dynamic_cast.

You can use dynamic_cast on the base pointer stored in your container to determine if the object is actually of a different type derived from your base class.

See the section on dynamic_cast here :

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Example

```
Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(ptr_base_class);
if (d) {/* We now know that ptr_base_class holds an object of type Derived */}
else {
   /// This object is not a Derived class type
}
```

However, if you had to iterate over your entire base class pointer list using dynamic_cast to determine if an object is of a specified type, it would be wasteful.

Here's where you answered your own question again. Keep a separate list of all Creature*s so you don't have to cast them. Yes, you will be using a /little/ more memory, but not much. Being able to iterate over the Creature list without iterating the entity list improves your performance. To make things easier, make your own container that has a list of each type of object as well as a main list of all objects. If you don't care about their derived class, iterate the main list. If you care about what class they are, iterate their specific list.